# Field has incomplete type error

Tags: c, struct, types, incomplete-type

In my C-code I've got a tcpsock.c and tcpsock.h file. The tpcsock.c file include's the tcpsock.h file. This socketcode is used in a connmgr.c (which includes tcpsock.c).
In the C file I've got two structs, which are defined as follows:

```
struct tcpsock{
   long cookie;
   int sd;
   char * ip_addr;
   int port;
};

struct conn{
   struct tcpsock_t socket;
   long last_active;
};
```

In the header file I have the following code:

```
typedef struct tcpsock tcpsock_t;
typedef struct conn conn_t;
```

When I try to compile this, I'm getting the following error:

```
In file included from connmgr.c:12:0:
lib/tcpsock.c:78:22: error: field ‘socket’ has incomplete type
struct tcpsock_t socket;
                 ^
```

I've been searching everywhere but wasn't able to find a solution, so I hope anyone here can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you typedef `struct tcpsock tcpsock_t`, what does it mean when you declare a variable as `struct tcpsock_t`?  `tcpsock_t` is what you need.

Comment: You `typedef`ed `tcpsock_t` so change the faulty member to `tcpsock_t socket;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`typedef struct tcpsock tcpsock_t;` defines `tcpsock_t` as a `struct tcpsock`. Hence, your struct definition must look like this:

```
struct conn{
   tcpsock_t socket;
   long last_active;
};
```

Comment: @Tibo You're welcome. I think you can mark this question as solved then ;-)